# increment an integer number and write in output xml in loop

Tags: python, arrays, xml

Im creating a xml file using element tree , i have almost completed except for one thing .

this is my build code

```
for i in range(colcolation):
    column = et.SubElement(metadatarecords, "metadata-record")
    colname = et.SubElement(column, "remote-name")
    colname.text = colName[i] 
    datatype = et.SubElement(column, "remote-type")
    datatype.text = colRtype
    Localname = et.SubElement(column, "local-name")
    Localname.text = colLName[i]
    Parentname = et.SubElement(column, "parent-name")
    Parentname.text = colpname
    Ordinal = et.SubElement(column, "ordinal")
    Ord  = str(i + 1)
    Ordinal.text = Ord

    if  colName[i] == 'Discount': 
        colld = et.SubElement(column, "precision")
        colld.text = precision
        aggred = et.SubElement(column, "aggregation")
        aggred.text = aggregationp
        ltyped = et.SubElement(column, "local-type")
        ltyped.text = localtypep
        print("1")
    else :
        if colName[i] == 'Profit':
            collp = et.SubElement(column, "precision")
            collp.text = precision 
            aggrep = et.SubElement(column, "aggregation")
            aggrep.text = aggregationp
            ltypep = et.SubElement(column, "local-type")
            ltypep.text = localtypep
            print("2")
        else:
            if colName[i] == 'Quantity':
                collq = et.SubElement(column, "precision")
                collq.text = precision
                aggreq = et.SubElement(column, "aggregation")
                aggreq.text = aggregationp
                ltypeq = et.SubElement(column, "local-type")
                ltypeq.text = localtypep
                print("3")
            else:
                collc = et.SubElement(column, "collation")
                collc.text = collation
                aggrec = et.SubElement(column, "aggregation")
                aggrec.text = aggregation
                ltype = et.SubElement(column, "local-type")
                ltype.text = localtype
                print("4")
            
    colnul = et.SubElement(column, "contains-null")
    colnul.text = containsnull
    attributes=et.SubElement(metadatarecords, "attributes")
    attribute=et.SubElement(attributes, "attribute")
    attribute.set('datatype','string')
    attribute.set('name','DebugRemoteType')
    attribute.text='WSTR'
```

this Ordinal tag needs to be printed as 1 ,2 ,3 dynamically for 12 times i.e from 1 to 12 automatically should increment.When i gave like above code im getting error " **TypeError: cannot serialize 1 (type int)**"

Can someone say how to do that ??

output sample is

```
      <metadata-record class='column'>
        <remote-name>Category</remote-name>
        <remote-type>130</remote-type>
        <local-name>[Category]</local-name>
        <parent-name>[Custom SQL Query]</parent-name>
        <remote-alias>Category</remote-alias>
        **<ordinal>1</ordinal>**
        <local-type>string</local-type>
        <aggregation>Count</aggregation>
        <contains-null>true</contains-null>
        <collation>LEN_RUS_S2_WO</collation>
        <attributes>
          <attribute datatype='string' name='DebugRemoteType'>&quot;WSTR&quot;</attribute>
        </attributes>
      </metadata-record>
      <metadata-record class='column'>
        <remote-name>City</remote-name>
        <remote-type>130</remote-type>
        <local-name>[City]</local-name>
        <parent-name>[Custom SQL Query]</parent-name>
        <remote-alias>City</remote-alias>
        **<ordinal>2</ordinal>**
        <local-type>string</local-type>
        <aggregation>Count</aggregation>
        <contains-null>true</contains-null>
        <collation>LEN_RUS_S2_WO</collation>
        <attributes>
          <attribute datatype='string' name='DebugRemoteType'>&quot;WSTR&quot;</attribute>
        </attributes>
      </metadata-record>
```

Thanks,
Aarush

Comment: Please fix your indentation, `else:` needs to be at the same level as `if`. Also, you should use `elif` for a series of mutually exclusive conditions, rather than nesting `if` inside `else:`

Comment: ok sure will change ..Thanks for the suggestion ..

Comment: Can ordinal be incremented dynamically inside the tags ???

Comment: What line is getting that error? Please show the full traceback.

Comment: While printing the metadata i have to set Ordinal tag like <Ordinal>1</Ordinal> , for next value it should be <Ordinal>2</Ordinal> ...till <Ordinal>12</Ordinal> .I have pasted my full code in top and bolded the line too . I want to know how to add an integer value to Ordinal.text when im writing the output

Comment: I understand that's what you're trying to do. You said you're getting an error, you didn't say which line is causing that error. Please post the traceback.

Comment: `Ord` is not an `int` because you did `Ord = str(i+1)`. So the error must be somewhere else.

Comment: ok , do you have any suggestion on how to add the ordial value inside the loop ..When i add Ordinal only its coming ...if i comment it and print its working .

Comment: " TypeError: cannot serialize 1 (type int)" thats the error im getting while writing in file

Comment: I know that's the error you got, you wrote that in the question. But there should be a traceback that shows what line the error happened on.

Comment: Thanks , I resolved it from the hint of your question . 
Ordinal = et.SubElement(column, "ordinal")
Ordinal.text = str(i + 1)

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. Using an intermediate variable should be exactly the same.